# Trigger content change in a separate column?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have been looking into a solution to achieve something similar to:
[image]

The way it works is that clicking or hovering on one of the headings in the left hand column will bring up different text in the right hand column.

The solution I am thinking is that I would use list items with a carousel to achieve this. But I am stuck as to how this is done and could do with some guidance. I cannot seem to find anything similar elsewhere.

Where I am so far - https://codepen.io/mattrees92/pen/KKmMMMV

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-lg-4">
  <li> Test 1 </li>
  <li> Test 2 </li>
  <li> Test 3 </li>
  <li> Test 4 </li>
</div>
<div class="col-lg-8">
  <div id="owl-example" class="owl-carousel">
    <div> pjiojifgjiojdiofjgodfjogjidofjiogjdiojgofjdogjfiojiodjgiofjgiodjfoijgiodfjiogjoidfjgiojdiofjgiojdifojgiodjfiogjiodjfgioj</div>
    <div> Your Content </div>
    <div> Your Content </div>
    <div> Your Content </div>
    <div> Your Content </div>
    <div> Your Content </div>
    <div> Your Content </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```
html {
padding-top: 50px;
}

li {
list-style: none;
}


$(document).ready(function () {
$("#owl-example").owlCarousel({
items: 1,
});
});
```

Cheers,

Answer (score 0):

There are **multiple** ways to achieve what you want.
One ( the most simple/straight forward i would say ) is just by using javascript and `index`es.

So if you hover on `1st` list item, the `1st` text item should be visible. And so on.

Check code below. I am using arrays and eventlisteners

*Just an FYI. When using `li` elements, wrap them inside an `ul` element*

```js
const listItems = document.querySelectorAll('ul li')
// turn nodeList returned by querySelectorAll into array using spread operator
// we will need array to get the index of the hovered element.
const arrListItems = [...listItems]
const list = document.querySelector('ul')
const textItems = document.querySelectorAll('.text div')
// add mouseover event listener
list.addEventListener('mouseover', (event) => handleHover(event))
const handleHover = (event) => {
// get index of the hovered element
  const index = arrListItems.indexOf(event.target)
  // remove class show-me from all items
  textItems.forEach(item => item.classList.remove('show-me'))
  // check if there is a textItem with the specific index
  // add ' show-me ' className to the item with the same index as the hovered list item
  textItems[index] &&
    textItems[index].classList.add("show-me");
}
```

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

ul {
  margin: 0 15px;
  padding: 0;
}

.text div {
  visibility: hidden;
}

.text div.show-me {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <ul>
    <li> Test 1 </li>
    <li> Test 2 </li>
    <li> Test 3 </li>
    <li> Test 4 </li>
  </ul>
  <div class="text">
    <div> Your Content 1</div>
    <div> Your Content 2</div>
    <div> Your Content 3</div>
    <div> Your Content 4</div>
    <div> Your Content </div>
    <div> Your Content </div>
  </div>
</div>
```